# Which of the following statements are necessarily true about $f,~g~?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f,g$ are measurable real valued functions on $\mathbb R$, such that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f^2(x)+g^2(x))dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$$Let $E=\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)\ne g(x)\}.$
Which 0f the following statements are necessarily true?

1. $E$ is the empty set
2. $E$ is measurable
3. $E$ has Lebesgue measure zero
4. For almost all $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$

Comment: is it csir question?

Comment: Here's one way to get started: the equation of integrals you have implies that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x)-g(x))^2 dx =0$. First make sure you see why, then see if it helps

Comment: @Bey: A ROUGH SKETCH: Then $f-g=0$ almost everywhere. So $E$ is measurable with measure $0.$ So (2) and (3) are true?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617808/lebesgue-measure-measurable-sets

Answer (score 2):

1) Take $f\equiv 1$ and $g(0)=0$, $ g(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$.

2) always holds for measurable functions ($E$ is the complement of the preimage of $\{0\}$ under the measurable map $f-g$

3) is true because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f-g)^2dx=0 \Rightarrow$ For almost all $x\in \Bbb R : f(x)-g(x)=0$

4) Same as 1)

Comment: to show only 2 and 3 are correct does my argument in the above comment work?

Comment: yes, it's essentially the same. For 2) I just wanted to give a hint how to show that sets of this type are measurable in general.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f^2(x)+g^2(x))dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ which gives
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f^2(x)+g^2(x)-2f(x)g(x))dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x)-g(x))^2 dx =0$.
 This gives $f(x)=g(x) \forall x$ 
but

E=$\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$. Hence $E$ has no elements. Hence it is measuarble and has measure 0

Comment: This does not hold if $f,g$ are not continuous. See my example below.